# Filter column based on other column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table `clicks` with the following fields:

- `date`
- `page_id`
- `clicks`

Its data looks like:

```
date           page_id     clicks
2015-01-01        1          20
2015-01-02        2          10
2015-01-02        2          5
2015-01-01        4          10
2015-01-02        5          5
```

There is another table with the page meta information, `pages`. Some pages are written in English and some in French. The English ones have IDs 1,2,3 and the French ones have ids 2,3,4

I'm trying to create a dataset which splits them into columns like:

```
date         french_page_clicks    english_page_clicks
2015-01-01         10                   20
2015-01-02         5                    15
```

The closest question I've found to this is: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/45532/create-multiple-columns-from-a-single-column-filtering-criteria where using `COUNT(IF(revision = 'pending', 1, NULL)) as pending,` they can insert `1` into the table. But I need to insert the actual sum of the clicks.

The furthest I've got (which doesn't work) is:

```
SELECT
    date,
    SUM (clicks) AS english_page_clicks IF page_id in (1, 2, 3),
    SUM (clicks) AS french_page_clicks IF page_id in (4, 5, 6)
FROM
    clicks
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date ASC
```

Or even better, the ability to just reference the pages table into the SUM() like:

```
SELECT
    date,
    SUM (clicks) AS english_page_clicks IF pages.lang = 'english',
    SUM (clicks) AS french_page_clicks IF pages.lang = 'french'
FROM
    clicks
INNER JOIN pages ON clicks.page_id = pages.id
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date ASC
```

How can I filter the columns to create the summary table above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move the expression into the aggregate function. Try this:

```
SELECT
    date,
    SUM(case when lang = 'English' then clicks else 0 end) AS english_page_clicks,
    SUM(case when lang = 'French'  then clicks else 0 end) AS french_page_clicks
FROM
    clicks
INNER JOIN pages ON clicks.page_id = pages.id
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date ASC
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/19277/1)

Comment: Superb. Also hadn't seen SQLFiddle before - great site!